# How can I offer concurrency with Pika in long-working consumers?

Tags: python, concurrency, rabbitmq, pika

Short version: How can I prevent blocking Pika in a Remote Procedure Call situation?

Long version:

None of the Pika examples demonstrate my use case.

I have a Tornado server which communicates with other processes/machines over AMQP (RabbitMQ, Pika). These other processes are not very well-defined, but they will, for the most part, be returning data (see the [RPC example on RabbitMQ's website](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html)). Sometimes, a process might need to take an extremely long time to process a large amount of information, but it shouldn't completely block smaller requests from being taken by the process. Or maybe the remote server is blocking because it sent out a web request. Think of it like a web server, but using AMQP instead of HTTP.

Since Pika documentation claims that it's not thread-safe, I cannot pass the connection to multiple threads (or processes, for that matter). What I want to do is start a new process, and add a socket event (for the pipe to that program) to the Pika IOLoop, as I would be able to do with Tornado. The Pika IOLoop is much different from the Tornado IOLoop, and it doesn't seem to support adding multiple handlers; it seems to operate using one "poller" on one socket.

I'd like to avoid requiring the Tornado package for this package, because I would only be using the IOLoop. It's not out of the question, but I want to see what my other options are, or if there is a solution to my problem by somehow connecting multiple Pika IOLoops/Pollers. RabbitMQ's documentation says that workers can often be "scaled up" by adding more. I'd like to avoid creating a connection for every request that comes in (if they're coming in fast).

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, I believe you unfortunately either need a different communication model or need multiple Pika IOLoops/Pollers/Redundant Connections.

It sounds like from documentation and from other sites that RPC in Pika is always a blocking statement and unable to be passed around between threads. See http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html where the author points out that RPC in Pika is inherently blocking once you actually call the ioloop.

```
"When in doubt avoid RPC. If you can, you should use an asynchronous pipeline - instead of RPC-like blocking"
```

If you want to keep sending multiple RPC calls on the same connection before one completes, you'll need a different Asynchronous model. Multiple RPC calls on the same connection before completion isn't the usual implementation of the RPC model, though it's not technically forbidden ( http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.progcomm%2Fdoc%2Fprogcomc%2Frpc_mod.htm ). I don't think Pika operates with this model, though it does have asynchronous support via callbacks (not what you are looking for I think).

If you just want to easily be able to generate new connections on the fly you could use a thread or process wrapper on a connection, where you create and block on the RPC in the other context and push to a common Queue which the main thread can monitor. Tornado might give you this, but I agree that it's a bit of overkill, and making such a connection wrapper shouldn't be all that difficult as I've done something similar for other I/O ops in less than 100 lines of Python (see Queue package for Threaded wrapper version). I think you already saw this possibility though based on your talk of multiple IOLoops.